# Sum based on date range in two separate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to sum all the value in one column based on a range of date in two column:

```
Start_Date  Value_to_sum  End_date
2017-12-13    2          2017-12-13
2017-12-13    3          2017-12-16 
2017-12-14    4          2017-12-15
2017-12-15    2          2017-12-15
```

A simple groupby won't do it since it would only add the value for a specific date.

We could do an embeeded for loop but it would take forever to run:

```
unique_date = carry.Start_Date.unique()
carry = pd.DataFrame({'Date':unique_date})
carry['total'] = 0
for n in tqdm(range(len(carry))):
    tr = data.loc[data['Start_Date'] >= carry['Date'][n]]
    for i in tr.index:
        if carry['Date'][n] <= tr['End_date'][i]:
                carry['total'][n] += tr['Value_to_sum'][i]
```

Something like that would work but like I said would take forever.

The expected output is unique date with the total for each day.

Here it would be

```
2017-12-13 = 5, 2017-12-14 = 7, 2017-12-15 = 9.
```

How do I compute the sum based on the date ranges?

Comment: Sorry my first language is french, you know you can edit my question for language related issue :)

Comment: I already did a little bit of that. This change seemed drastic enough that I wanted to make sure you didn't really mean "recursive".

Comment: what is your expected out put

Comment: No problem, sorry my error

Comment: I have added my expected output

Comment: why don't you slice the original df first based on the date range and get the sum of the resulting df?

Comment: won't work.... this would give the same result as a groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, group by ["Start_Date", "End_date"] to save some operations.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
df_g = df.groupby(["Start_Date", "End_date"]).sum().reset_index()

def my_counter(row):
    s, v, e = row.Start_Date, row.Value_to_sum, row.End_date
    if s == e:
        c[pd.Timestamp(s, freq="D")] += row.Value_to_sum
    else:
         c.update({date: v for date in pd.date_range(s, e)})

df_g.apply(my_counter, axis=1) 
print(c)
"""
Counter({Timestamp('2017-12-15 00:00:00', freq='D'): 9,
     Timestamp('2017-12-14 00:00:00', freq='D'): 7,
     Timestamp('2017-12-13 00:00:00', freq='D'): 5,
     Timestamp('2017-12-16 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3})
"""
```

Tools used:

> Counter.update([iterable-or-mapping]):
>   Elements are counted from an iterable or added-in from another mapping (or counter). Like dict.update() but **adds counts instead of replacing them**. Also, the iterable is expected to be a sequence of elements, not a sequence of (key, value) pairs. -- Cited from [Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

[pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html)

Comment: Nice answer and very clean

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a way to do this without involving at least one loop.  You are trying see if a date is between your start and end date.  If it is, you want to sum the `Value_to_Sum` column.  We can make your loop more efficient.

You can create a mask for each unique date and find all rows that match your criteria.  You then apply that mask and take the sum of all matching rows. This should be much faster than iterating over each row individually and determining what date counters to increase.

```
unique_date = df.Start_Date.unique()
for d in unique_date:
    # create a mask which will give us all the rows 
    # that we want to sum over
    # then apply the mask and take the sum of the Value_to_sum column
    m = (df.Start_Date <= d) & (df.End_date >= d)
    print(d, df[m].Value_to_sum.sum())
```

This gives you the output you want:

```
2017-12-13 5
2017-12-14 7
2017-12-15 9
```

Someone else might be able to come up with a clever way to vectorize the entire thing, but I'm not seeing a way to do it.

Comment: Nice answer but since my data is huge and I need quick execution I doubt I can use your solution :)

Comment: How large are we talking?  How many unique dates do you have?

Comment: Also, are your date columns just strings, or are they Python datetimes?

Comment: about 4000 dates but there is multiple process before and after. This solution is already much faster then what I had but without any loop would be the best

Comment: datetime , do you think string would be faster ?

Comment: No. There might be something we can do with datetimes but I don't necessarily know if it will be faster.  You could do to pre-process the dataframe to make this process faster, but you'd likely need a loop to do it.  So it's either you introduce a loop before this process or during it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the sum to be part of the original dataframe you can use apply to iterate on each row (but this might not might the most optimized code as you are calculating the sum on every row)

```
carry['total'] = carry.apply(lambda current_row: carry.loc[(carry['Start_Date'] <= current_row.Start_Date) & (carry['End_date'] >= current_row.Start_Date)].Value_to_sum.sum(),axis=1)
```

above will result to

```
>>> print(carry)
     End_date  Start_Date  Value_to_sum  total
0  2017-12-13  2017-12-13             2      5
1  2017-12-16  2017-12-13             3      5
2  2017-12-15  2017-12-14             4      7
3  2017-12-15  2017-12-15             2      9
```